# Зачем нам лишние запятые

Tags: вводные

Возможно () потому

1)  Надо ли ставить запятую?  "Конечно! -  скажете вы. - Это же вводное слово". Вот и примеры: "Возможно, потому и жив по сей день". "Возможно, потому, что не стоило вставлять три картины в один эпизод". "Возможно, потому, что архитектура здания в чем-то созвучна его творчеству".

2) Но во всех этих примерах нет паузы между вводным словом и местоимением,  они тесно связаны и семантически, и интонационно. И это интуитивное понимание отражено в оформлении примерно таких же предложений: "Возможно потому оно так мне интересно". "Возможно потому, что не люблю рано вставать". "Возможно потому, что всё построено на контрастах".

3) Так кто же прав?  Слово «возможно» может быть наречием, например:  «Я хочу, чтобы мы встретились возможно скорее».  Почему бы не считать, что здесь оно также выступает в роли наречия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Но во всех этих примерах нет паузы между вводным словом и местоимением, они тесно связаны и семантически, и интонационно.

А синтаксически? Это самое важное.

> > И это интуитивное понимание отражено в оформлении примерно таких же предложений: "Возможно потому оно так мне интересно". "Возможно потому, что не люблю рано вставать". "Возможно потому, что всё построено на контрастах".

В первом запятая необходима.
Во втором тоже, если это не "Это возможно потому, что не люблю рано вставать".
То же и в третьем. "Это возможно потому, что все построено на контрастах". В других случаях запятая необходима.

Comment: В приведенных примерах слово "возможно" не является сказуемым, поэтому, согласно Вашему мнению, его нужно обособлять во всех случаях, будто бы синтаксис этого требует. Но я думаю, что синтаксис вводных предложений - вещь очень смутная и мало изученная, в нем очень много противоречий, а приведенные предложения - это только один пример. В своем ответе я попробую его объяснить.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуем доказать правильность предложений, в которых вводное слово не обособляется.

А. В качестве примера рассмотрим три предложения, которые  оформлены без учета официальных правил, но согласно их различной семантике, структуре, интонации:

(1) Он еще не приехал, ВИДИМО, ПОТОМУ ЧТО в окнах нет света (значение причины, обособление вводного слова, нет ударения на местоименной части союза, нет расчленения союза).

(2) Он еще не приехал, ВИДИМО, ПОТОМУ ЧТО  задержали дела (значение причины, обособление вводного слова, нет ударения на местоименной части союза, нет расчленения союза).

(3) Он еще не приехал видимо потомУ, что  задержали дела (следственно-причинное значение, нет обособления вводного слова, ударение на местоименной части союза, расчленение союза).

Б. Согласно официальным правилам эти предложения оформляются ОДИНАКОВО (обособляется вводное слово, расчленяется союз), но при этом у них РАЗНАЯ ИНТОНАЦИЯ И РАЗНЫЕ ОТТЕНКИ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ. В предложении (1) вводное слово однозначно относится к главному предложению. Предложения (2) и (3) – это разное оформление одного предложения. В предложении (2) вводное слово относится к придаточному предложению. В предложении (3) вводное слово вместе с местоименной частью союза относится к главному предложению.НО НИЧЕГО ЭТОГО НЕ ОТРАЖАЕТ ФОРМАЛЬНОЕ ПРАВИЛО.

В. А теперь попробуем РАСЧЛЕНИТЬ предложения и взять только вторую часть в качестве ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНОГО предложения. Но это получается только для предложений 1 и 3:

(1) Он еще не приехал, видимо.  Потому что в окнах нет света.

(2) Он еще не приехал. Видимо, потому что  задержали дела (это предложение вычеркиваем, нечитаемая структура; невозможно одновременно обособить вводное слово и поставить ударение на местоимении).

(3) Он еще не приехал. Видимо потому, что  задержали дела.

Предложение (3) - это и есть образец, в котором не обособлено вводное слово.

Comment: София, вы подняли вопрос, который возникал у меня в связи с обособленными конструкциями. Вводное слово не отделяется от обособленного оборота, но всегда отделяется от придаточного, хотя интонация в этих случаях очень похожа. "Он опоздал, видимо, потому что задержался на работе". "Он опоздал, видимо задержавшись на работе". Но при тире или скобках вводное отделяется: "Недалеко от деревни мы нашли чудесные места для рыбной ловли (впрочем, не единственные на этих речках)".

Comment: Отсутствие запятой подчеркивает, что вводное относится к обороту, когда может возникнуть двусмысленность. Другой способ избежать двусмысленности - дополнительное тире. Именно оно и используется перед придаточным, чтобы подчеркнуть связь с ним вводного слова.
А вообще вопрос, к чему относится вводное, еще не решен: одни считают, что к обеим частям, между которыми находится, а другие - что к последующей части и никакой двусмысленности нет. То есть конструкция "Он еще не приехал, видимо" неестественна. Этот смысл передается так: Он, видимо, еще не приехал.

Comment: А при парцелляции запятая ставится и перед обособленным оборотом. Получается, что она не интонационная, а смысловая.

Comment: А вот в таком, к примеру, тексте надо обязательно обособлять вводное слово? "Роль контраста в романе  определить не просто, иногда приходится подумать. Возможно потому, что и в  жизни,  и литературе всё построено на контрастах". Можно ли обойтись без гирлянды запятых, которые не проясняют структуру предложения, а напротив, затемняют ее?

Comment: Структурная запятая убирается, только если искажается смысл. Здесь он не искажается, поэтому запятая нужна, иначе "возможно" становится сказуемым, то есть смысл искажается уже по-другому (что возможно?). И перед "напротив" запятая нужна, иначе получается "не проясняют, а напротив" вместо "не проясняют, а затемняют".